# Can the data root be merged or whole data state changed in vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I am just started using vue.js version 2.1.10.
Consider see the following snippet:

```
app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js',
    date: '01/01/2017'
  }
});
```

I could not find any reference in docs which explained how to change or merge the whole *data* (e.g. I received new state by an ajax call) without explicitly changing all data attributes one by one.

In my project I've end up with:

```
data: {
   item: {
      message: "...",
      date:    "..."
   }
}
```

But it looks cumbersome in template.
Please answer if you know how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not cumbersome at all and it's actually quite common.

```
data: {
    item: {
        message: "...",
        date:    "..."
    }
},
methods: {
    updateItem() {
        $.ajax(...)
            .then((response) => {
                this.item = response
            })
    }
}
```